# Repetition of a word in String with out using collections

Tags: java, string

Can any one suggest me to write a logic for this without using collections.

I have a string s="This is the place called island and it is a nice place ";

Input String to find repetition word is: "is";

output should be : 4

Comment: If you are using Java I think Regex is the best way instead of all the string operations. Check my post below for regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below logic to do it.

1. Split the String on whitespace.
2. Initialize an integer counter to 0.
3. Traverse through each of the elements of the resultant array and for each String element of the array, do the following:
   a) If `stringElement.contains("is")`, increment the counter created in step 2.
   b) If `!stringElement.contains("is")`, do nothing and move on to the next element.
4. Do this till you exhaust all the elements of the array.
5. Print the counter value.

Try to write the code for this on your own and get back here if you're stuck up anywhere.

Comment: The function should be `String.contains(String)` otherwise the "is" in "this" will not be recognized.

Comment: @SteveBenett - Thanks for the correction! I made the necessary edit in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string s="This is the place called island and it is a nice place ";   
s = s+" ";
System.out.println(s.split("is").length-1);
```

Comment: that would fail on string like "penis" ;)

Comment: so add a space before or after it

Comment: sometimes you can't modify the input

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
int count = 0;
for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex >= 0; startIndex = str.indexOf("is", startIndex)) {
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method, it should work:

```
public static int countSubStrings(String subString, String mainString){
    return (mainString.length() - mainString.replace(subString, "").length()) / subString.length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. Hope you are using Java.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 String str = "This is the place called island and it is a nice place";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("is");
    Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
        count++;

    System.out.println(count);    // prints 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method will count how many time s2 appears in s1

```
public static int CountStr(String s1,String s2){
        int cnt=0,temp=0;
        if(s1.indexOf(s2)>0){
            temp=s1.indexOf(s2);
            cnt++;
        }
        while(s1.indexOf(s2,temp+1)>0){
            cnt++;
            temp=s1.indexOf(s2,temp+1);
        }
        return cnt;
    }
```